# How to remove the title bar from a dialog window (called via Office.js Dialog API), or from an Office Add-in task pane?

Tags: office-js

I want to create a floating command bar that takes as little screen real estate as possible for a Word add-in using the Office JS API. How might I remove the title bar from a dialog generated via the dialog API? If this is not possible, can the title bar removed from a Taskpane. Or is there another way to generate a bare bones floating command bar on the Desktop (e.g., a jquery dialog or Fabric UI component)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to change or remove the dialog title. (But that's a great idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).)

In the meantime, you could try the Fabric Modal or Fabric Dialog components:

[Fabric Modal](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/modal)

[Fabric Dialog](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/dialog)

By the way, taskpanes themselves can float and you can have more than one taskpane open at the same time, so you could have one that is your floating command bar. However, there is no way to programmatically detach a taskpane or set its dimensions, so you would need to instruct the user how to do this.